# LED dimming light fixtures

Tags: wiring, lighting, led

Can I wire two dimming led light fixtures to one dimmer? (0-10V control)
My dimmer has 6 wires. AC in, AC out, and 0-10V out.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.  The magic of. 0-10V is that it can control lights on

- different AC power branches
- different circuits
- different panels
- different *services*
- different voltages (120V vs 277V)

You name it.

You simply share the 0-10V wires via cabling rated for the duty.  If the 0-10V wires are intermixing with AC mains wires, then the cabling must be UL listed for AC mains, such as THHN or Romex.

Comment: @manassehkatz nah, just keep using the rudder to keep the airplane on the runway centerline.   Seriously the 0-10V source should be isolated from mains.